# How to reference groupby index when using apply, transform, agg - Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, aggregate

To be concrete, say we have two DataFrames:

df1:

```
    date    A
0   12/1/14 3
1   12/1/14 1
2   12/3/14 2
3   12/3/14 3
4   12/3/14 4
5   12/6/14 5
```

df2:

```
        B
12/1/14 10
12/2/14 20
12/3/14 10
12/4/14 30
12/5/14 10
12/6/14 20
```

Now I want to groupby date in df1, and take a sum of value A in each group and then normalize it by the value of B in df2 in the corresponding date. Something like this

```
df1.groupby('date').agg(lambda x: np.sum(x)/df2.loc[x.date,'B'])
```

The question is that neither aggregate, apply, nor transform can reference to the index. Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `.groupby('column')` it makes `column` to be part of `DataFrameGroupBy` index. And it is accessible through `.index` property.

So, in your case, assuming that `date` is NOT part of index in either `df` this should work:

```
def f(x):
    return x.sum() / df2.set_index('date').loc[x.index[0], 'B']

df1.set_index('date').groupby(level='date').apply(f)
```

This produces:

```
               A
date            
2014-01-12  0.40
2014-03-12  0.90
2014-06-12  0.25
```

If `date` is in index of df2 - just use `df2.loc[x.index[0], 'B']` in the above code.

If `date` is in `df1.index` change the last line to `df1.groupby(level='date').apply(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df_grouped = df1.groupby('date').sum()
> print df_grouped['A'] / df2['B'].astype(float)
date
12/1/14    0.40
12/2/14     NaN
12/3/14    0.90
12/4/14     NaN
12/5/14     NaN
12/6/14    0.25
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is currently in the Low Quality queue. Please provide some explanation