# Can I add a conditional count() to a groupby dataframe where the condition is a groupby result?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have a two column dataframe with name limitData where the first column is CcyPair and second is trade notional

```
CcyPair,TradeNotional  
USDCAD,1000000  
USDCAD,7600  
USDCAD,40000  
GBPUSD,100000  
GBPUSD,345000  
etc
```

with a large number of CcyPair's and TradeNotional's per CcyPair. From here I generate summary statistics as follows

```
limitDataStats = limitData.groupby(['CcyPair']).describe()
```

This is easy enough. However, I would like to add a column to sumStats that contains the count of TradeNotional's greater than that ccyPair's 75% determined by .describe() stored in limitDataStats. I've searched a great deal and tried a number of variations but can't figure it out. Think it should be somewhere along the lines of the below (I thought I could reference the index of the groupby as mentioned here but that gives me the actual integer index [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221041/how-to-reference-groupby-index-when-using-apply-transform-agg-python-pandas)

```
limitData.groupby(['CcyPair'])['AbsBaseTrade'].apply(lambda x: x[x > limitDataStats.loc[x.index , '75%']].count())
```

Any ideas? Thanks, Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter values greater than the 75th percentile and then count how many are greater than or equal to that value (used `.sum()` since boolean series is returned from `ge()`)

```
limitData.groupby('CcyPair')['AbsBaseTrade'].apply(                      
                                    lambda x: x.ge(x.quantile(.75)).sum()))
```